# Mod Haskell Homework

Tags: haskell

My homework was to provide a function that computes 'x^y mod n' -for any n < (sqrt maxint32)

So I started by writing doing this:

```
modPow :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int 
modPow x y n = (x `mod` n) ^ (y `mod` n) `mod` n
```

Which seemed to work fine, for any number of n, although my next homework question involved using x^n mod n = x (Camichael numbers) and I could never get modPow to work.

So I made another modPow using pseudocode for mod exponentiation, -from wikipedia:

```
modPow2 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int 
modPow2 x y n 
 = loopmod 1 1
  where
   loopmod count total = if count > y
                          then total
                           else loopmod (count+1) ((total*x) `mod` n)
```

Which now correctly produces the right answer for my next question, (x^n mod n = x) -for checking for Camichael numbers.

ALTHOUGH, modPow2 does not work for big numbers of 'y' (STACK-OVERFLOW!!)

How could I adjust modPow2 so it no longer gets a stackoverflow in the cases where y > 10,000 (but still less than sqrt of maxint 32 -which is around 46,000)

Or is there a fix on my original modPow so it works with x^n mod n = x? (I always do 560 561 561 as inputs and it gives me back 1 not 560 (561 is a carmichael number so should give 560 back)

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because the argument `total` is computed lazily.

If you use GHC, you can make `loopmod` strict in `total` by placing a ! in frontof the argument, i.e.

```
loopmod count !total = ...
```

Another way would be to force evaluation of total like so: Replace the last line with

```
else if total == 0 then 0 else loopmod (count+1) ((total*x) `mod` n)
```

This does not change semantics (because `0*x`is 0 anyway, so the reminder must be 0 also) and it forces hugs to evaluate total in every recursion.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks so much!! Any reason why it works -how does it force hugs?

Comment: Steven - it's actually easy to see if one is trained to: In your version, you nowhere need to actually calculate the value of total inside loopmod, therefore, as Haskell is a non-strict language, it is not done. But in the version I propose, you have to evaluate total to decide the next step (i.e. return 0 or do a new recursion)

Comment: The easy rule is thus: if a value is needed in order to decide whether recursion takes place or not, then this value must be evaluated right away. If this value is an argument, the function will be strict in this argument.

Comment: Thanks, you've been a great help! :)

Answer (score 6):

Your formula for `modPow` is wrong, you can't just use *y mod n* as the exponent, it will lead to wrong results. For example:

```
Prelude> 2^10
1024
Prelude> 2^10 `mod` 10
4
Prelude> 2^(10 `mod` 10) `mod` 10
1
```

For a better `modPow` function you could use that `x2n+1 = x2n ⋅ x` and `x2n = xn ⋅ xn` and that for *multiplication* you actually *can* simply use the `mod` of the factors.

Answer (score 4):

Where did you get your formula for `modPow` from?

`` (x ^ y) `mod` n `` = `` ((x `mod` n) ^ (y `mod` φ n)) `mod` n `` where [`φ` is Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Comment: Must have mis-interpreted it off the sheet >.< :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for implementation ( a^d mod n ) then

```
powM::Integer->Integer->Integer->Integer
powM a d n
   | d == 0 = 1
   | d == 1 = mod a n
   | otherwise = mod q n  where
       p = powM  ( mod ( a^2 ) n ) ( shiftR d 1 ) n
       q = if (.&.) d 1 == 1 then mod ( a * p ) n else p
```

Comment: Instead of `(.&.) d 1 == 1`, just use `odd d`.